# Как обратиться к странице с настроенным фильтром на определенный раздел?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, filter

Приветствую всех. Есть у меня на странице фильтр такого вида:

```html
<div class="filter_outer">
  <div class="filter_holder">
    <ul>
      <li class="label"><span data-label="Фильтр">Фильтр</span><i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="filter active" data-filter="all"><span>Все</span>
      </li>
      <li class="filter" data-filter="event"><span>Event</span>
      </li>
      <li class="filter" data-filter="main"><span>Разделы</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы я мог обратиться к этой странице извне по ссылке уже с определенным фильтром по конкретному разделу event - вида: `<a href="[http://ссылка/(data-filter=event)]">ссылка</a>`[1](http://%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0/(data-filter=event)) ?
Если недостаточно условий или не знаете как - большая просьба не минусовать! а просто об этом сообщите мне об этом плиз

Comment: кому-то лишь бы только минусовать.. я ведь привел минимальный пример, по-моему вполне конкретный вопрос. если так нельзя сделать, то так и подскажите - за что сразу минусы??...

Comment: "_Данный вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он не понятен или не несет пользы_" (Из всплывающей подсказки на кнопочке "вниз").

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev почему? в какой критерий из этого списка он, как вам кажется, попадает?

Comment: "_Не отражает стремления разобраться_" + "_не несет пользы_". А что касается минимального примера, то приведенный в вопросе код им **не является**. Я не могу засунуть его в JSFiddle и получить воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev "Не отражает стремления разобраться" - а что же тогда несет вопрос как не стремление разобраться? "не несет пользы" - почему не несет пользы? разве это не полезно знать - можно ли в ссылке указывать и обращаться оп дата-атрибуту? Категорически с вами не согласен!

Comment: @Вася Добавьте подробностей в вопрос. Что фильтрует этот фильтр и как? Приведите код Javascript и укажите что вы пытались сделать чтобы он реагировал на пареметры запроса.

Comment: Вопрос слишко общий и вам на него наврядли дадут конкретный ответ. 1) Вы можете указывать в ссылке GET параметры, а на странице уже в зависимости от переданных параметров выполнять нужные вам действия (парсите URL и делаете что вашей душе угодно). 2) Любой нормальный фильтр при фильтрации добавляет свои параметры к адресной строки что позволяет оставлять фитры активными при перезагрузки страницы, если у вашего фильтра есть такое, то тогда можете разобраться какие параметры генерирует фильтр и подставить свои.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Варинат 1

Переписать фильтр на нормальную форму с использованием `GET` параметров и ссылками вида

```
<a href="http://ссылка?filter=event">ссылка</a>
```

### Вариант 2

Либо костыль на `js` с помощью хеша в урл:

```
$(function(){ // document ready
    var filter = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    $('.filter[data-filter="' + filter + '"]').click(); // если у вас есть событие на клик
});
```

Ссылка будет вида

```
<a href="http://ссылка#event">ссылка</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**У меня похожая проблема.** И Суть скорей всего в чем то простом.

Имеется страница где фильтруются блоки. Проще было (во много раз) создать 7 разных страниц. Но мне было интересно довести дело до конца именно таким образом. Может сейчас и переделаю....

*Вот оригинал страницы*  https://sibirpotok.ru/service.html

Слева перечисляются услуги. Когда заходим на страницу  все блоки на одной странице. Если нажимать на меню слева - фильтруется нужный блок. Нужно имитировать, что страницы разные. Еще если страницу обновить нужно автоматически выполнять скрипт чтоб остаться в том же пункте меню. Иначе опять выпадут все блоки на одной странице.

У меня не получается сделать запуск кнопок даже на той же странице, через верхнее выпадающее меню. А еще нужно сделать запуск кнопок при переходе с других страниц, через выпадающее сверху меню.

Вот что есть о фильтре в "джеквери"

```
        // filter items when filter link is clicked
        $('#filtrable a').on('click', function(e)
        {


            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({ filter: selector, layoutMode : 'fitRows' });
            // return false;
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        var $optionSets = $('#filtrable li'),
            $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');


            $optionLinks.on('click', function(e){
                var $this = $(this);
                // don't proceed if already selected
                if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
                  // return false;
                  e.preventDefault();
                }
                var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filtrable');
                $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $this.addClass('selected');

                // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
                var options = {},
                    key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
                    value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
                // parse 'false' as false boolean
                value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
                options[ key ] = value;
                if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
                  // changes in layout modes need extra logic
                  changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
                } else {
                  // otherwise, apply new options
                  $container.isotope( options );
                }

                // return false;
                e.preventDefault();
            });



// $(function(){
```

//
//  var hash = location.hash.substr(1)
//
//   $('[data-value="'+hash+'"]').click();
//
//});

```
 $(function(){ 
 var filter = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
$('.filter[data-filter="' + filter + '"]').click(); // если у вас есть событие на клик
```

});

```
})(jQuery);
```

В самом низу пытался добавлять код jQuery, который нашел здесь. Может не туда добавляю или не так )))

И еще подскажите может где то есть готовые шаблоны по такому принципу, чтоб сделать. И самое главное хостинг вроде ява-скрипт не поддерживает.